# Symfony form builder radio buttons

Tags: php, symfony

I am using Symfony 3 framework, and I need to create a form that will display a quiz question, and image and four possible answers as radio buttons.
So far I have created the fields id,question and image that are mapped to my entity fields from my database but having problem with the radio buttons. Bellow is what I have so far.

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
    $builder
        ->add('id',HiddenType::class)
        ->add('image',TextType::class)
        ->add('question',TextType::class)
        ->add('Options to choose',ChoiceType::class,
                array('choices' => array(
                        'answer1' => '1',
                        'answer2' => '2',
                        'answer3' => '3',
                        'answer4' => '4'),
                'choices_as_values' => true,'multiple'=>false,'expanded'=>true))
        ->add('Submit',SubmitType::class);
}
```

My problem are the following:

->add('Options to choose' I cannot have this, because Symfony is trying to find methods in my entity class. 
Also bellow 'answer1' => '1' is not getting the data from the database. How can I pull the data from the database and display it for each radio buttons.
How can I solve this issues and have 4 radio buttons that display the 4 database options. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It looks like the [entity type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

What you've done so far looks more like a form which will create a question.

Use entity field and choices options :

```
$builder->add('answer', EntityType::class, array(
'class' => 'AppBundle:Answer',
'choices' => $question->getAnswers(),
```

));

Your goal is to build a form with one question and its answers. Can you show us your entities ? Quiz, Question and Answer i guess.

Comment: I only have one entity: Questions. In the database the table questions has  thees fields: id, question, image, answer1, answer2, answer3,answer4. Thees fields are mapped in my entity with geters and setters. I am trying to build a form with a quiz questions and its answers. I am at the beginning of learning symfony. Maybe this is not the right approach to build a form and have only one entity.

Comment: Maybe I can don't have to use a form. Maybe I can just display the data in a view, and then find a way to know which answer the user has choose.

Answer (score 0):

You could mapped your "Options to chose" to false

`$builder->add('Options to chose', ChoiceType::class, array(
    'choices' => array(
        'm' => 'Male',
        'f' => 'Female'
    ),
    'mapped'    => false,
));`

And then do some buisness logic to get the answers as choice and save the answer in a field. But I realy don't recommand this approach.

If you are learning Symfony, take a look to at [Databases and Doctrine documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#entity-relationships-associations), you need to handle the answers, and even the quiz itself, via entities and create the relations between. And then learn how to use them in a form. It will be much more simple and dynamic !

```
class Question
{
    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Answer", mappedBy="question")
    */
    private $answers;
}

class Answer
{
    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Question", inversedBy="answers")
    */
    private $question;
}
```